# Explain me about std::function handling by class member method

Tags: c++, std-function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class world
{
public:
    void hello(){
        std::cout << "wow" << std::endl;
    }   
};
int main(void)
{
    std::function<world&,void()> pFn = &world::hello; //is this right???
};
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work :(
how to handle it?
please explain me cool way

Comment: Please include the error message in the question. What do you want to achieve? Is your aim to write `pFn()` to call `hello` ?

Comment: Yes i want pFn() to call world::hello

Comment: Making `hello` static and using `std::function<void()> pFn = &world::hello;` is one way to make it work.

Comment: Aren't you trying to call a member function by `std::function`? Then it should be like this: `std::function<void(world&)> pFn = &world::hello;`

Comment: @JohnPark 
it is occured error 
(No matching function for call to object of type 'std::function<void (world &)>')

Comment: @배주원, Did you declare a instance of `world` and pass it to `pFn()`? It should be, `world w;   pFn(w);`

Comment: @배주원, To call a member function, you need a instance of the class or the function must be declared `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is:

> ```
> template< class >
> class function; /* undefined */
> template< class R, class... Args >
> class function<R(Args...)>;
> ```

Your `std::function<world&,void()>` doesn't make sense. You are supposed to pick the function type you want to store in the function object.

Next, you need a `world` to call one of its non-static member functions.

What you can do is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class world
{
public:
    void hello(){
        std::cout << "wow" << std::endl;
    }   
};
int main(void)
{
    //std::function<world&,void()> pFn = &world::hello; //is this right???    
    world w;
    std::function<void()> pFn = [&w](){ w.hello();};
    pFn();
}
```

You need to make sure `w` is still alive when you call `pFn()`. Alternatively you could make `pFn` take a `world` as parameter, in either case you need an instance to call a non-static member function.

PS: Note that in the above example there is really no point in using the `std::function` when you can use the lambda itself. `std::function` comes for a price that often you do not need to pay.